# Regular Expression for Dummies

Tags: php, regex

Is there any resource out there that covers regular expression in a very basic starter level? I have looked at http://www.regular-expressions.info/ but it is not exactly 'quick reference' friendly..  any other sources?

For me I mostly use it in php, so php friendly would be helpful.

Comment: How is http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html not 'quick reference' friendly? :)

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regex+tutorial

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=regular+expression+cheat+sheet

Comment: Thanks everyone, Wesley from that list I found http://www.addedbytes.com/download/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v2/png/ which is exactly what I need.  thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at these:
http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php
http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/15-php-regular-expressions-for-web-developers

Answer (score 2):

When I was starting out with regular expressions I got recommended this book: [Mastering Regular Expressions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124). It really helped me understand the basic concept and how regular expressions work. But also I can still learn from it today because it also covers more advanced topics.

There are some pdf versions of the books out there, but I don't think they are legal. Otherwise I would really recommend buying this book if you really like to actually understand regexp and not just copy ready regexps and kind of understand how it works.

Comment: +1000 Best book on regex ever. An _excellent_ tutorial, it is clear, thorough, and even funny at times. The third edition covers PHP in-depth. The Slashdot review gave it 11 out of 10 and I wholeheartedly agree.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows, you can use this program http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/
It's mostly for .net but can apply to any regex scenario. 
There's a quick reference on the side and you can build and test your expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Sams Teach Yourself Regular Expressions in 10 Minutes gave me a very good start. Everything about RegEx is not taught in 10 minutes but each different aspect of RegEx is broken in to easy to understand ~10 minute sessions.

To actually test RegEx's, [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com) was awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic [php tutorial](http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-regular-expression.html)

You may find also some online regex testers useful, where you can play around with regular expressions.

[Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/) or [Regexr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Answer (score 0):

The best one I found out of these so far is http://www.addedbytes.com/download/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v2/png/ from Wesley Murch's post above.  I didn't even think about searching for 'cheat-sheet' in google.. thanks!